# Facing an error while running vscode extension sample: "Cannot find module 'vscode'"

Tags: node.js, npm, vscode-extensions

I am trying to run one of the vscode extension samples from [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/helloworld-minimal-sample). When I run using the below command, I get error that vscode is not found. However, vscode is present in node_modules and @types/vscode is specified in package.json. I also tried installing using yarn. Still no luck.

>>> node extension.js

```
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'vscode'
Require stack:
- /Users/kkrithika/Documents/Projects/Salesforce/research/vscode-extension-samples/helloworld-minimal-sample/extension.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:956:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:804:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/kkrithika/Documents/Projects/Salesforce/research/vscode-extension-samples/helloworld-minimal-sample/extension.js:3:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/kkrithika/Documents/Projects/Salesforce/research/vscode-extension-samples/helloworld-minimal-sample/extension.js'
  ]
}
```

>>> node --version

v16.17.1

>>> package.json

```
{
    "name": "helloworld-minimal-sample",
    "description": "Minimal HelloWorld example for VS Code",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "publisher": "vscode-samples",
    "repository": "https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/helloworld-minimal-sample",
    "engines": {
        "vscode": "^1.74.0"
    },
    "activationEvents": [],
    "main": "./extension.js",
    "scripts": {},
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/vscode": "^1.73.0"
    }
}
```

>>> extension.js

```
// The module 'vscode' contains the VS Code extensibility API
// Import the module and reference it with the alias vscode in your code below
const vscode = require('vscode');

// this method is called when your extension is activated
// your extension is activated the very first time the command is executed

/**
 * @param {vscode.ExtensionContext} context
 */
function activate() {
    // Use the console to output diagnostic information (console.log) and errors (console.error)
    // This line of code will only be executed once when your extension is activated
    console.log('Congratulations, your extension "helloworld-minimal-sample" is now active!');
}

// this method is called when your extension is deactivated
function deactivate() {}

activate()
```

Comment: `node extension.js` is wrong. Read https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension and learn your mistake.

Comment: Have you installed the node packages for this project (`npm i`)?

Comment: @MikeLischke yes I have installed.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use Node.js to run the extension code, use the Run Extension instead.
the "Run Extension" is configured by the launch.json in the folder of .vscode, and make sure putting .vscode folder under the root directory of your workspace.
The other thing need to attention is the "runtimeExecutable args" and "outFiles" configs in the launch.json, which need to correspond to your actual coding path